# No SMS/MMS Notification Sound Sporadically for only a Specific Contact?

Tags: notifications, sms, audio, htc-desire

**Phone:** HTC Desire 530s - MetroPCS Stock Rom - Android 6.0 - Rooted.

**The Issue:** No notification sound for a specific contact. Call notifications seem to come through from said contact, but SMS/MMS are problematic.

Issue has been present for months. In the last few minutes, the phone has received messages from said contact. The only notifications that did sound were when looking at the phone, but that in itself was also sporadic. Some texts made noise while looking at the phone, most still did not.

During this same up-time, without any reboots etc, I received a audible notification for numerous text messages from another contact, in any phone state (Looking at the SMS tread, looking at another application, phone screen off, etc.)

Listening to any other audio source, or notifications from anyone else sound fine. Music plays uninterrupted even if you tap on the phone etc, so the speakers seem to be OK.

Doesn't make sense that it's because the screen is off/"sleeping" as the d$%n thing makes every other notification for every other contact and/or type of notification.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Wild guess - 1. It's a SIM contact 2. It's *not* a Google contact but maybe through other social media apps 3. Try deleting the contact and adding it again

Comment: @beeshyams Thank you. I will make sure it's deleted from both SIM and Google, and see what happens. I swear I've tried un-linking and deleting it, but I'll try again, and check SIM. Thanks.